# Problemas ao organizar uma struct em C

Tags: c

Estou tendo problema ao organizar os dados de uma struct, os dados até estão organizando, mais acabo sempre recebendo lixo de memoria na primeira posição, as demais são organizadas normalmente sem erros. A estrutura deve ficar em ordem decrescente de acordo com o dado int pont da struct classificados.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

   typedef struct concurso
  {
  char nome[30];
  int matri;
  int prov1;
  int prov2;
  int prov3;
}con;

typedef struct clasificados
{
  char n[30];
  int m;
  int pont;
}cla;

void ordena(con* co,int tam)
{
  cla *conc=(cla*)malloc(sizeof(cla)*tam);
  cla aux;
  int i,j=0;
  for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
  {
  if((co[i].prov1>40)&&(co[i].prov2>40)&&(co[i].prov3>40)&&(co[i].prov1+co[i].prov2+co[i].prov3>=150))
  {
    conc[j].pont=co[i].prov1+co[i].prov2+co[i].prov3;
    strcpy(conc[j].n,co[i].nome);
    conc[j].m=co[i].matri;
    j++;
  }
  }
//O PROBLEMA ESTA DAQUI PARA BAIXO, AQUI QUERO ORDENAR OS DADOS DA STRUCT CLASSIFCADOS, ATE QUE ORDENA, MAIS O PRIMEIRO ELEMENTO SAI COMO LIXO DE MEMORIA
    for( i=0; i<j; i++ )
    {
      if( conc[i].pont < conc[i+1].pont )
      {
        aux.pont = conc[i+1].pont;
        conc[i+1].pont = conc[i].pont;
        conc[i].pont = aux.pont;

        strcpy(aux.n,conc[i+1].n);
        strcpy(conc[i+1].n,conc[i].n);
        strcpy(conc[i].n, aux.n);

        aux.m = conc[i+1].m;
        conc[i+1].m = conc[i].m;
        conc[i].m = aux.m;
        i=-1;
      }
    }

    printf("\n\t\t------Classificados-------\n");
    printf("\nPOSICAO\t\tMATRICULA\tCANDIDATO\tNOTA\n");
    for( i=0; i<j; i++ )
    {
      printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%3d\n",i+1,conc[i].m,conc[i].n,conc[i].pont);
    }
    free(conc);
}

int main()
{
  int i,j;
  int tam;
  printf("Digite o numero de candidatos: ");
  scanf("%d",&tam);
  con *c=(con*)malloc(sizeof(con)*tam);

  for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
  {
    printf("Digite o nome do candidato %d: ",i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",c[i].nome);

    printf("Digite a matricula do candidato %s: ",c[i].nome);
    scanf("%d",&c[i].matri);

    printf("Digite a nota 1 do candidato %s: ",c[i].nome);
    scanf("%d",&c[i].prov1);

    printf("Digite a nota 2 do candidato %s: ",c[i].nome);
    scanf("%d",&c[i].prov2);

    printf("Digite a nota 3 do candidato %s: ",c[i].nome);
    scanf("%d",&c[i].prov3);
  }
  ordena(c,tam);

  free(c);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Testei de uma forma rápida o seu código, e pareceu-me funcionar corretamente. [Confirme aqui no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Gc9VtK) se não era o resultado que esperava. Por isso convido-o a detalhar melhor o problema. Quais as entradas que utilizou para que não funcione ? Lembro que quando gera os classificados se apenas um se qualificar tem um problema no `if` que testa logo dois elementos do array.

Comment: Então, nos compiladores on-line o código não apresenta problemas, mas nos locais como code blocks, dev; acontece esse erro que mencionei de imprimir lixo de memória na primeira posição.

Comment: Nao entendi  esse problema do "if", poderia me exemplificar melhor. Obrigado

Comment: Eu executei no codeblocks e correu igual ao que aparece no Ideone. Quais os valores exatos que está a usar como entrada? E o problema vem neste `if` => `if( conc[i].pont < conc[i+1].pont )` que de acordo com o `for` anterior não ha garantia que `i+1` seja um elemento valido

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar sobre o if.

Comment: Sobre os valores, estou usando valores aleatórios, ja fiz vários testes, sempre tenho o mesmo erro, mas agora com seu depoimento vou verificar meus compiladores, e testar em outro pc, ai volto aqui, obrigado

Comment: Aproveite e teste com os valores que o link que eu passei no Ideone utiliza. E coloque aqui os valores que está a testar e que diz que falham, para que eu possa testar também e perceber se existe de facto algum problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara basicamente o seu erro está no `for`, o seu `for` está da seguinte maneira, `for( i=0; i<j; i++ )`, desta maneirai quando você faz o seu vetor no índice `i + 1`, quando seu `for`, chegar no ultimo loop ele irá dar buffer overflow, e estourar a posição de memória pertencente ao seu vetor.

Para arrumar este erro basta na condição do seu `for` você colocar, `i < j - 1`, fiando da seguinte maneira `for( i=0; i<j-1; i++ )`.

Sem mais delongas aqui está a resposta completa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct concurso
{
    char nome[30];
    int matri;
    int prov1;
    int prov2;
    int prov3;
} con;

typedef struct clasificados
{
    char n[30];
    int m;
    int pont;
} cla;

void ordena ( con* co, int tam )
{
    cla* conc = (cla*)malloc(tam * sizeof(cla));
    cla aux;
    register int i , j;

    for ( i = 0, j = 0 ; i < tam; ++i ) {
        if ( (co[i].prov1 > 40) && (co[i].prov2 > 40) && (co[i].prov3 > 40) && (co[i].prov1 + co[i].prov2 + co[i].prov3 >= 150) )
        {
            conc[j].pont = co[i].prov1 + co[i].prov2 + co[i].prov3;
            strcpy(conc[j].n, co[i].nome);
            conc[j].m = co[i].matri;

            ++j;
        }
    }

    /*  O PROBLEMA ESTA DAQUI PARA BAIXO,
        AQUI QUERO ORDENAR OS DADOS DA STRUCT CLASSIFCADOS,
        ATE QUE ORDENA, MAIS O PRIMEIRO ELEMENTO SAI COMO LIXO DE MEMORIA   */
    for ( i = 0; i < j - 1; ++i ) {
        if ( conc[i].pont < conc[i+1].pont )
        {
            aux.pont = conc[i+1].pont;
            conc[i+1].pont = conc[i].pont;
            conc[i].pont = aux.pont;

            strcpy(aux.n,conc[i+1].n);
            strcpy(conc[i+1].n,conc[i].n);
            strcpy(conc[i].n, aux.n);

            aux.m = conc[i+1].m;
            conc[i+1].m = conc[i].m;
            conc[i].m = aux.m;

            i = -1;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\t\t------Classificados-------\n");
    printf("\nPOSICAO\t\tMATRICULA\tCANDIDATO\tNOTA\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < j; ++i )
        printf("%i\t\t%i\t\t%s\t\t%3i\n", i+1, conc[i].m, conc[i].n, conc[i].pont);

    free(conc);
}

int main()
{
    register int i,j;
    int tam;
    con* c;

    printf("Digite o numero de candidatos: ");
    scanf(" %i", &tam);

    c = (con*)malloc(tam * sizeof(con));

    for ( i = 0; i < tam; ++i ) {
        printf("Digite o nome do candidato %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", c[i].nome);

        printf("Digite a matricula do candidato %s: ", c[i].nome);
        scanf(" %i", &c[i].matri);

        printf("Digite a nota 1 do candidato %s: ", c[i].nome);
        scanf(" %i", &c[i].prov1);

        printf("Digite a nota 2 do candidato %s: ", c[i].nome);
        scanf(" %i", &c[i].prov2);

        printf("Digite a nota 3 do candidato %s: ", c[i].nome);
        scanf(" %i", &c[i].prov3);
    }

    ordena(c,tam);

    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado ;).

Comment: obrigado cara, tinha solucionado o problema fazendo outra função, mas ajudou muito, muito obrigado